# How to exclude something from the keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, windows-phone-8.1, inputscope

Is it possible on a windows phone to exclude something from the keyboard? I want to exclude the "," and keep only the "." character  on the keyboard with `InputScope="Number"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remove individual keys from the built in keyboard, only use [one of the valid values for `InputScope`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.input.inputscopenamevalue.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1).

Instead you should validate the value (after all, `,` is the thousands separator in most cultures where `.` is the decimal separator (and vice versa in some)) for characters you don't want for your purpose, or do what some apps have done, and implemented a keypad with just the buttons you want as a control for use in your views.